I have a 7.9MM record CSV file to import into Excel. How do I read portions of the CSV file to subset the data?
I have a 53 variable, 7.9MM row CSV file to import into Excel. This exceeds the row limit for Excel. I would like to import a set of 8 files, each containing about 1 million rows from the CSV into Excel. Using Excel, how can I subset the importation of rows into 1 million records each eventually importing all the data from Csv into Excel? The base file contains a header row naming the columns.
I have used to import feature in Excel, which reaches the line limit.
I asked ChatGPT3.5 to write code importing the subset, and the following is what I am attempting to use:
Sub ImportCSVSubset()
    Dim CSVFilePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Define the CSV file path
    CSVFilePath = "C:\Users\mmcbu\Desktop\GAVR\GAVRdata\GAVR.csv"
    
    ' Define the worksheet to import the data
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your desired sheet name
    
    ' Define the range of rows to import
    startRow = 1 ' Start importing from row 2
    endRow = 1000 ' Import until row X, change as needed
    
    ' Clear existing data in the worksheet
    ws.UsedRange.Clear
    
    ' Open the CSV file and read the data
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & CSVFilePath, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True ' CSV files are typically comma-delimited
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1) ' Array(1) for all text data
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    
    ' Delete extra rows if the imported data exceeds the specified range
    If ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row > endRow Then
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(endRow + 1, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    ' Delete rows above the specified range
    If startRow > 1 Then
        ws.Rows("1:" & startRow - 1).Delete
    End If
    
    ' Adjust column widths
    ws.Columns.AutoFit
    
    MsgBox "CSV data imported successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub

This code imports 1,048,576 rows correctly. however, I have requested only 1000 rows. Any suggestions on how to limit the number of rows to the limit requested?

Asking the dumb question: why do you need Excel for this?

You need to use an editor or a script of some kind to extract the records you want.  If you have Unix-like tools available, head and tail could do this easily.

ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row > endRow will be False if the entire column A is populated.

Reply to BigBen: At the moment Excel is the only analytical tool available.

R is free as are many other apps

@cybernetic.nomad but the corporate overlords may not allow it :-)

Whether you have a single CSV file with 7.9 million rows or 8 CSV files of about a million rows each, you can use Power Query to Get Data either from that single file or specify the multiple files by importing from a folder.
If you need to display the data, use Power Query to subset, splitting them into separate tables of ~1 million rows each, and load the tables, which will automatically create a new sheet from each table.
But if you need the data loaded to eventually use a Pivot Table to analyze it, you can load as "Only Create Connection." This won't populate the data, but it will maintain a connection to your CSV file(s) to perform the anlysis.

This problem is solved using brute force. I "discovered" Git Bash and used the SPLIT command to subset the larger file into chunks I can manage. Thank you for the replies.
